# Accessing an object class variable in ArrayList (java)

Tags: java, arraylist

So, let's say i have a class to describe a book

```
   public class Book {
     String name;
     int pages;
     String auother;
     boolean available;
     String rentername;
  }
```

Now, i have set an array list to contain the unknown numbers of books i wish to have/add/delete during the running time.
The thing is, when i try to accesses a certain book in the arraylist by an index i get an error.

```
enter code here

ArrayList Books = new ArrayList();
Book bk1 = new Book();
Books.add(bk1);
System.out.println(Books[0]. --->>> won't give me accesses to the 'Book' class variables (name, pages...)
```

So, how can i make it to the class variables?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is an implementation of a [`java.util.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) collection backed by a dynamic array.

This means three things.

Firstly, you don't need to worry about resizing, allocating or coping elements into the array, the `ArrayList` will take care of it for you.

Secondly, any method that wants a `List` doesn't care about the implementation (you could pass a `LinkedList` instead) which decouples the code (meaning you can change the implementation without adversely effecting those who rely on it, because of the contract made through the `List` interface)

Thirdly, to interact with the contents of the `List`, you need to use one or more of the interfaces access methods.

You already know about `add`, but to obtaining an object, you need to use [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) which;

> Returns the element at the specified position in this list

You might also be interested in

- [`remove(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) and [`remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [`set(int, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29)
- [`contains(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [`indexOf(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [`size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29)

There are other methods, of course, but these are the immediately useful.

I'd also have a read through the [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

**UPDATED example**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {

        List<Book> listOfBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
        Book bk1 = new Book();
        listOfBooks.add(bk1);

        System.out.println("           bk1 = " + bk1);
        System.out.println("listOfBooks(0) = " + listOfBooks.get(0));

    }

    public class Book {

        String name;
        int pages;
        String auother;
        boolean available;
        String rentername;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Book: name = " + name + "; pages = " + pages + "; available = " + available + "; rentername = " + rentername + "; hashCode = " + hashCode();
        }

    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
           bk1 = Book: name = null; pages = 0; available = false; rentername = null; hashCode = 1137551390
listOfBooks(0) = Book: name = null; pages = 0; available = false; rentername = null; hashCode = 1137551390
```

Comment: When i use the get methood, i can't get accsess to the book object varibable (name, pages etc...i can only view the generic object methood such as qeuals/get class/ HashCode...

Comment: The first problem you have is you are using a vanellia version of `List`, which accepts any type of `Object`, but will only return a `Object`.  You can can fix this by 1. casting the result back to a `Book` (`Book book = (Book)Books.get(0)`), but this dangerous and should be avoided where possible. 2. Take advantage of `Generics`, this basically restricts the `List` to only dealing with certain types of `Objects`.  I've update my post with an example, but you might want to have a read through the [Generics Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more information

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`get(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) method of `List` to get the entry you want:

```
System.out.println(Books.get(0));
```

You cannot access the entries of a `List` with the notation used for arrays.

BTW: Please stick to the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Comment: When i use the get methood, i can't get accsess to the book object varibable (name, pages etc...i can only view the generic object methood such as qeuals/get class/ HashCode...

Comment: @user3921 Of course you can't. They are neither public, nor do you have getter/setter methods. Change/Add those and you will be able to access them.

Comment: Hey, im sorry my friend, but adding public didn't solve it, i even attached a photo for you guys to see...http://i45.tinypic.com/wtswj.jpg

Comment: @user3921 That's because you use an untyped `ArrayList`. Use `ArrayList<Book>` wherever your `ArrayList` contains `Book`s. Otherwise Java and Eclipse cannot know that the `ArrayList` contains `Book`s and consequently cannot access the attributes. (you can make them private again afterwards).

Answer (score 2):

You need to create public setters and getters method to access fields, and to access book instance you need to

```
books.get(index)
```

Comment: Or, for a pure data class, it's probably fine to make the fields public. Accessors and mutators would just be boilerplate for such a class unless they did bounds checking or other validation.

Comment: accessor can be used in future also there are many frameworks which may look for accessor if used against them